# Getting NoneType error when parsing xml file in python

Tags: python, nltk

I have this kind of xml file:

```
<dep type="nsubj">
            <governor idx="7">open</governor>
            <dependent idx="5">it</dependent>
          </dep>
          <dep type="aux">
            <governor idx="7">open</governor>
            <dependent idx="6">will</dependent>
          </dep>
          <dep type="ccomp">
            <governor idx="3">announced</governor>
            <dependent idx="7">open</dependent>
          </dep>
```

I want to parse it and extract the deep type, i.e., like nsubj, aux, ccomp etc. I'm doing like this:

```
file_list=[]
with open(xml_file) as f:
    page = f.read()
f.close()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page,"xml")
for types in soup.find_all('dep'):
    file_list.append(types.string.strip())
print file_list
```

But, I'm getting NoneType error. Why is it so?

EDIT:

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/akritibahal/Downloads/stanford-corenlp-2012-07-09/testing.py", line 103, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/akritibahal/Downloads/stanford-corenlp-2012-07-09/testing.py", line 102, in main
    extract_top_dependencies('/Users/akritibahal/Downloads/stanford-corenlp-2012-07-09/test')
  File "/Users/akritibahal/Downloads/stanford-corenlp-2012-07-09/testing.py", line 80, in extract_top_dependencies
    file_list.append(types.string.strip())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'
```

EDIT2:

I think it's coz how I have been doing xml parsing is that it reads between the <>  these tags. But for dep, I want to extract what's there in type=, and there is nothing between the open and close tags. How to do that?

Comment: Please edit the full traceback where you get the NoneType error into your question.

Comment: Which line causes this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your edit (and the name `types` in your original `for` statement), you appear to be after the tag attributes rather than the string. To access the tag attributes, try something along the following lines instead:

```
>>> xml = """<root><dep type="nsubj">
            <governor idx="7">open</governor>
            <dependent idx="5">it</dependent>
          </dep>
          <dep type="aux">
            <governor idx="7">open</governor>
            <dependent idx="6">will</dependent>
          </dep>
          <dep type="ccomp">
            <governor idx="3">announced</governor>
            <dependent idx="7">open</dependent>
          </dep></root>"""
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(xml)
>>> for dep in soup.find_all('dep'):
    print dep.attrs.get('type')

nsubj
aux
ccomp
```

In other words, I think you want something like this instead:

```
>>> for dep_elem in soup.find_all('dep'):
        type_ = dep_elem.attrs.get('type')
        if type_:  # be sure type_ is not a NoneType
            file_list.append(type_.strip())
```

See the documentation [here](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#attributes).

Answer (score 0):

Remove the

```
f.close()
```

line! It is done automatically when using the `with open()` syntax and also the  name `f` is only valid inside the with block.

Comment: I think it's coz how I have been doing xml parsing is that it reads between the <> </> these tags. But for dep, I want to extract what's there in type=, and there is nothing between the tags. How to do that?